# Is it possible to create executable for Mac on Linux?

Tags: python, linux, macos, executable

I am using Linux, Fedora 18, 64bit. I'd like to know, is there a way to create **Mac** executable on **Linux**, from Python source code?

Comment: Does running Mac OS X in a virtual machine (VirtualBox) count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but you need a cross compiler. There's one here:

[IMCROSS](http://www.sandroid.org/imcross/)

Comment: Ok, thanks. But is it possible to use Py2App for example?

Comment: I expect so, but you would need to insert the cross compiler into its toolchain.

Comment: It may not be easy. One of the things py2app does is use macholib to find dylib dependencies, and without a full set of system dylibs and frameworks it's going to end up thinking it's missing all kinds of requirements it needs to package up. Maybe if you can install a MacOSX10.foo.sdk and configure it properly? But I'm not sure that's easy, or legal...

Comment: @abarnert, I am going to use IMCROSS :-)

Comment: @Vik2015: Using IMCROSS doesn't magically fix everything. In particular, you still need to install a MacOSX10.foo.sdk and get it set up (at least there are instructions for doing so—but they're two major versions out of date…), and you will probably still need to fight with py2app.